# Why we need user level and kernel level threads

Tags: operating-system

Why we need user level and kernel level threads if, for any execution of user level thread we need to map it to kernel thread.

Comment: It takes 2-6 us to make a  waiting kernel thread ready and dispatch it onto a core, (assuming a core is available).  In some apps, under some circumstances, in some environments, the faster switching between user threads can make sense when weighed against the disadvantages.  Not encountered any myself:)